# Mongoose query for parent then child object and update child

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

My data structure looks as follows

```
[
        {
            "_id": "642e9f78abebcdd68147d6aa",
            "name": "test two",
            "priority": 0,
            "users": [
                {
                    "admin": true,
                    "role": 3,
                    "_id": "642aa3df4add92f56fe8caab"
                },
                {
                    "admin": false,
                    "role": 1,
                    "_id": "642bf3865808d8888a1995b4"
                }
            ],
            "createdAt": "2023-04-06T10:31:20.033Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-04-06T10:31:27.863Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
```

I would like to find the project by id ( "_id": "642e9f78abebcdd68147d6aa")

then find the user by id ("_id": "642aa3df4add92f56fe8caab")

and update the user.

I tried to findOne and update

```
 const projects = await Project.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        _id: projectId,
        "users._id": user._id,
      },
      {
        $set: {
          users: update,
        },
      }
    );
```

however, this approach updates the whole "users" array instead of just one specific one that matches the search.

my next attempt was:

```
  const projects = await Project.findOneAndUpdate(
      { projectId },
      { $set: { users: update } },
      { arrayFilters: [{ "users._id": user._id }] }
    );
```

however, this gives me the following error

```
MongoServerError: The array filter for identifier 'users' was not used in the update { $setOnInsert: { createdAt: new Date(1680862292699) }, $set: { users: [ { admin: false, role: 3, _id: ObjectId('642fec54b0a5eea143444e16') } ], updatedAt: new Date(1680862292699) } }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$elemMatch` like below and use this object in to mongoose query. I think it will help you.

```
{
_id:"642e9f78abebcdd68147d6aa",
users: { $elemMatch: { _id:"642aa3df4add92f56fe8caab"}
}
```

More clarification about `$elemMatch` visit this link https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/

Comment: i wasn't able to apply this successfully,

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer, to update such nested files you can use the following:

```
const projects = await Project.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        _id: projectId,
        "users._id": user._id,
      },

      {
        $set: { "users.$": { ...update, _id: user._id } },
      },
      {
        new: true,
      }
    );
```